# Macro too big to run, keeps 'not responding'

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

Hi I have now managed to write my macro but the whole thing stops responding, just a guess but i presume it is because it is asking to check too much data? I have about 3000 rows (but have even tried it on 10). Does anyone know how I can cut this down or mend it to work? Another query on it I have gone to the heading 'sample187' but ideally wanted it to go to 'sample400'?

Thanks

```
Sub Newmacro()
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strWhere As String
Dim i As Integer


strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT a.[A], " _
& "(SELECT Max([Serial]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A) As Serial, " _
& "(SELECT Max([Sample1]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample1, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample2]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample2, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample3]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample3, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample4]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample4, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample5]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample5, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample6]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample6, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample7]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample7, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample8]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample8, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample9]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample9, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample10]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample10, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample11]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample11, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample12]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample12, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample13]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample13, " _
& "(SELECT Max([Sample14]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample14, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample15]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample15, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample16]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample16, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample17]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample17, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample18]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample18, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample19]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample19, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample20]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample20, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample21]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample21, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample22]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample22, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample23]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample23, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample24]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample24, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample25]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample25, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample26]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample26, " _
& "(SELECT Max([Sample27]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample27, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample28]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample28, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample29]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample29, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample30]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample30, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample31]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample31, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample32]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample32, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample33]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample33, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample34]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample34, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample35]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample35, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample36]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample36, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample37]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample37, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample38]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample38, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample39]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample39, " _
& "(SELECT Max([Sample40]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample40, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample41]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample41, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample42]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample42, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample43]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample43, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample44]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample44, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample45]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample45, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample46]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample46, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample47]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample47, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample48]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample48, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample49]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample49, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample50]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample50, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample51]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample51, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample52]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample52, " _
& "(SELECT Max([Sample53]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample53, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample54]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample54, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample55]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample55, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample56]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample56, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample57]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample57, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample58]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample58, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample59]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample59, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample60]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample60, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample61]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample61, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample62]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample62, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample63]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample63, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample64]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample64, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample65]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample65, " _
& "(SELECT Max([Sample66]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample66, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample67]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample67, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample68]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample68, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample69]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample69, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample70]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample70, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample71]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample71, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample72]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample72, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample73]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample73, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample74]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample74, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample75]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample75, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample76]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample76, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample77]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample77, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample78]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample78, " _
& "(SELECT Max([Sample79]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample79, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample80]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample80, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample81]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample81, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample82]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample82, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample83]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample83, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample84]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample84, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample85]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample85, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample86]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample86, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample87]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample87, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample88]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample88, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample89]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample89, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample90]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample90, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample91]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample91, " _
& "(SELECT Max([Sample92]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample92, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample93]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample93, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample94]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample94, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample95]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample95, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample96]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample96, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample97]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample97, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample98]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample98, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample99]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample99, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample100]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample100, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample101]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample101, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample102]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample102, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample103]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample103, " _
& "(SELECT Max([Sample104]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample104, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample105]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample105, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample106]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample106, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample107]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample107, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample108]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample108, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample109]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample109, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample110]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample110, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample111]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample111, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample112]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample112, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample113]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample113, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample114]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample114, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample115]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample115, " _
& "(SELECT Max([Sample116]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample116, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample117]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample117, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample118]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample118, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample119]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample119, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample120]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample120, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample121]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample121, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample122]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample122, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample123]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample123, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample124]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample124, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample125]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample125, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample126]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample126, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample127]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample127, " _
& "(SELECT Max([Sample128]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample128, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample129]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample129, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample130]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample130, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample131]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample131, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample132]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample132, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample133]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample133, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample134]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample134, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample135]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample135, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample136]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample136, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample137]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample137, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample138]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample138, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample139]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample139, " _
& "(SELECT Max([Sample140]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample140, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample141]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample141, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample142]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample142, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample143]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample143, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample144]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample144, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample145]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample145, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample146]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample146, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample147]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample147, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample148]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample148, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample149]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample149, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample150]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample150, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample151]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample151, " _
& "(SELECT Max([Sample152]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample152, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample153]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample153, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample154]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample154, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample155]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample155, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample156]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample156, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample157]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample157, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample158]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample158, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample159]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample159, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample160]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample160, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample161]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample161, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample162]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample162, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample163]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample163, " _
& "(SELECT Max([Sample164]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample164, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample165]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample165, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample166]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample166, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample167]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample167, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample168]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample168, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample169]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample169, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample170]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample170, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample171]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample171, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample172]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample172, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample173]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample173, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample174]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample174, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample175]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample175, " _
& "(SELECT Max([Sample176]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample176, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample177]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample177, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample178]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample178, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample179]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample179, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample180]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample180, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample181]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample181, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample182]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample182, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample183]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample183, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample184]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample184, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample185]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample185, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample186]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample186, " & "(SELECT Max([Sample187]) FROM [Data$] b WHERE b.[A]=a.A ) As Sample187 " _
& "FROM [Data$] a " _
& "GROUP BY a.[A]"

rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3

For i = 0 To rs.fields.Count - 1
    Sheets("Duplicated").Cells(1, i + 2) = rs.fields(i).Name
Next

Worksheets("Duplicated").Cells(2, 2).CopyFromRecordset rs
Sheets("Duplicated").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you written that macro in? From the code I'd guess it's Excel, but you should really tell us those nifty little details.

Comment: It appears to be VB Script given the use of `CreateObject(...)`. It looks like this data should really be in a database instead of being in Excel and accessed like it's a database.

Comment: On an unrelated note: this really looks like a query that should be 1.) seriously refactored and/or 2.) be generated programmatically by your code based on some information. It looks horribly inefficient and typo-prone as it is.

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner...how would I put this in a database?

Comment: @pjp: I can see what you're thinking, but it's VBA (and from the use of ActiveWorkbook, specifically Excel). VBScript doesn't allow Dim As - everything's a Variant. I'd prefer to see evidence of explicit references to ADO and early binding using `Set .. As New ...` but the CreateObject - which is being used in a very VBScript-y way, stuff is hardly the biggest problem. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has grown very far from the original example you posted. I will answer, based on that original example, that you can use max without the sub queries if you still only have True / False records:

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strWhere As String
Dim i As Integer

''http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246335

strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT a.[Name], Max([Black]) As Black, Max([Blue]) As Blue,Max([Green]) As Green " _
       & "FROM [Sheet3$] a " _
       & "GROUP BY a.[Name]"

rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3

For i = 0 To rs.fields.Count - 1
    Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(1, i + 1) = rs.fields(i).Name
Next

Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Comment: Hi does this mean if it the column has a '1' or blank rather than words? Thanks

Comment: It says too many fields defined. I have gone upto 261 columns. Is this too big? THanks

Comment: It also says record is too large.

Comment: I have not tested with 261 columns. If you do not have to do this very often, it may be best to create a list of names (SELECT [Name] from [sheet3%] group by [name] ) and then work through the original spreadsheet for each name using VBA to pull the row of data. It really seems like something that should be in a database.

Comment: Hi thanks, I have been able to do it for the number of columns needed now-it's a little tempermental sometimes! Thanks again I think I can finally put this one to rest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the query that's causing the problem, but that would be my first concern - it's horrible. I can't see any reason for all those correlated sub-queries. Nor can I see any purpose in the self-join. It looks like you're trying to get the maximum value for each sample for each value of `A`? Without anything on which to test it, I'm only guessing, but I'd say that this:

```
Dim sampno As Integer

strSQL = "SELECT a.[A], Max(a.Serial) As Serial"
For sampno = 1 To 187
    strSQL = strSQL & ", Max(a.Sample" & sampno & ") As Sample" & sampno
Next
strSQL = strSQL & " From [Data$] a" _
    & " GROUP BY a.[A]"
```

would give the same results.

400 fields would be a problem in any version of Excel pre-2007 (because those versions only supported 256 columns), otherwise 400 should be fine.

Comment: I am trying to dedupe against column A and then add on data (columns 'sample1' to 'sample187') from duplicate rows if data is found-basically concatenate the data onto on respondent.